# How i can resolve conflict type AcfLink

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, graphql, gatsby, wp-graphql

I have a problem with Gatsby, I have a type conflict in Link relation in WordPress

```
Fields "button" conflict because they return conflicting types AcfLink and String. Use different aliases on the fields to fetch both if this was intentional.

 Error path: undefined
```

in query request

```
button {
      url
      title
    }
```

How do I resolve this conflict

Answer (score 0):

You can alias both fields with:

```
button {
      newName1: url
      newName2: title
    }
```

After that, you will need to refer to each field using `button.newName1` and `button.newName2` respectively.

GraphQL aliases docs: https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases